# fetching data dynamically from sql

Tags: php, jquery

My jQuery part isn't working, can sombody please explain why I do not get the desired output ?
**index.php**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    array_push($result, array('text' =>$row[1]));
echo json_encode(array("result"=> $result));
```

**getting.js**

```
$.getJson("view_note.php", function(data){
            $("ul").empty();

            $.each(data.result,function(){

            $("ul").append("<li>Text: "+this['text']+"</li><br />";
            });
        });
    });
```

**Output**
[image: OutPut]

Comment: igonre the vertical line

Comment: You will have to add some debug output. On php side: what does `$result` finally contain? On JS side: what does `data` contain? On network level: what is transferred? Those are all things only you can find out, we do not have access to your system...

Comment: Lesson 1: Learn to debug my friend. You can use **console.log(data);** to view what kind of data are you receiving. Another thing I see in your code is you have to remove the **<br />**

Comment: The error is uncaught syntax error

Comment: there are a syntex error in ur each loop. u can check it in below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

$.getJson("view_note.php", function(data){
    $("ul").empty();

    $.each(data.result,function(){

        $("ul").append("<li>Text: "+this['text']+"</li><br />");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use each loop as

```
$.each(data.result,function(i,item){
            $("ul").append("<li>Text: "+$(item).text+"</li>";
            });
```

also remove `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you wrap the array 2 times.

```
echo json_encode(array("result"=> $result));
```

to

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: The variable $result is already an array from what I see coz you use array_push to insert the data and then you use echo json_encode(array("result"=> $result)); to put it inside another array. That's why you got the answer still in {}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the syntax (AFAIK), this is your code formatted and with syntax fixed:

```
$.getJson("view_note.php", function(data){
    $("ul").empty();

    $.each(data.result,function(){
        $("ul").append("<li>Text: "+this['text']+"</li><br />");
    });
});
```

*I'd prefer this to be a comment but I cannot because of the size and formatting constraints*

Answer (score 0):

You can change to this:

```js
var data = [{
  "result": [{
    "text": "My first note."
  }, {
    "text": "My Second note."
  }]
}]
$.each(data[0]['result'], function(i, item) {
  $("ul").append("<li>Text: " + item.text + "</li>");
  //-----------add index ----------^-----put closing-^-----here.
  // also no need to add <br> tag at the end.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```